# What is the state of matter of a substance if the melting point or boiling point of a substance is exactly at room temperature(25 degree Celsius)?

Tags: physical-chemistry

[image]

A substance can exist both in solid and liquid state at melting point, and A substance can exist both in liquid or gaseous state at boiling point. In the above image the state of matter is differentiated in solid, liquid or gas on basis of what the state of matter is the substance at room temperature (25 degree Celsius)(i.e. if the substance is at liquid state at room temperature (25 degree Celsius) than the substance is liquid). What if the melting point or boiling point of the substances is exactly at room temperature (25 degree Celsius) .it can exist both in solid or liquid state at 25 degree Celsius if it's boiling point is equal to 25 degree Celsius, and it can exist both in liquid or gaseous at 25 degree Celsius if it's boiling point is exactly equal to 25 degree Celsius. What will be the state of matter of that substance?

Comment: Well, it can be either solid or liquid or a mixture, depending on the heat content added.

Comment: The answer is: Temperature is not sufficient info to determine the state of matter at these cases.

Comment: You should look at  a phase diagram, (which shows pressure vs temperature) such as for water or benzene etc. If you fix just the temperature then it is possible for example, to be either in the gas or liquid phase. Only if  pressure and temperature are both fixed to be on a line in the phase diagram will, for example, a solid or liquid be in equilibrium.

Comment: It could be a gas. The physical state depends not only on the temperature but also on the pressure. And you can observe multiple physical states in the same system, even if at the same temperature and pressure. In the end, the cited statement is a bit too brief to be accurate. Room temperature, I think, is 20 degC now, not 25 degC.

Comment: This person should buy a bottle of tertiary butyl alcohol and observe it over the four seasons [global warming permitting] and occasionally open the bottle and take a sniff. If a liquid and solid are in equilibrium and there is a head space, this is a triple point. The triple point is a function of an inert gas pressure because there is an additional component in the Phase Rule.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways of differentiating the state of matter of a sample, by directly observed properties, and by the nature of intermolecular (or interionic) interactions.

##### 1. Properties

You can differentiate by whether the sample takes the shape of the container (assuming there is some gravity) and whether it has a definite volume or fills out the available space.

##### 2. Interactions

Solids and liquids have interactions between particles, gases do not. In solids, the interactions are long-lived with the same partner, in liquids interaction partners change. In solids, sometimes it is difficult or impossible to decide what the particles are (e.g. diamond is one single molecule).

#### Assigning a physical state to a substance

You would test the physical state of the pure substance at atmospheric pressure and room temperature. This does not mean this substance always has that physical state, it depends on the circumstances (pure or not, interactions with other substances, etc.).

The elements are labeled as a single physical state in some periodic tables, using the rationale above. If you can't get a sample of pure substance (e.g. highly unstable, radioactive elements), then you can't assign a physical state. I don't think there is any element where the normal melting point or boiling point is so close to room temperature to make it ambiguous.

> [OP] What is the state of matter of a substance if the melting point or boiling point of a substance is exactly at room temperature(25 degree Celsius)?

That depends on the specifics. Sometimes, you will have the substance in two or three physical states at the same time.

Here is a [textbook problem](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Saint_Francis_University/CHEM_113%3A_Human_Chemistry_I_(Muino)/01%3A_Matter_and_Measurements/1.02%3A_States_of_Matter) and the model answer to illustrate the complexity:

> Isopropyl alcohol is a colorless, flammable chemical compound with a strong odor. Its melting point is -89°C and it boiling point is 82.5°C. Is isopropyl alcohol a solid, liquid or gas at room temperature (25°C).
>
> Solution: Since room temperature (25°C) is above the melting point of isopropyl alcohol (-89°C), but lower than its boiling point (82.5°C), it is a liquid at room temperature.

The answer is a bit incomplete. If the alcohol is stored with some air above it, there will also be some isopropanol in the gas phase. This is how we smell liquids - some molecules enter our noses in the gas phase. If store in an open bottle outside or in a building with good ventilation, all of the alcohol will eventually evaporate (in a building with bad ventilation, the open bottle will pose a health and fire hazard).

Answer (score 0):

Heat is never distributed equally across an object, so if you have an object at 25 °C then that temperature is only an average measure of the energies of the particles which make it up. For example this means that in any liquid you have some particles with enough energy to become a gas, which is why water evaporates in the sun on 30 °C days. To answer your question then it doesn't matter if the object is sitting exactly at its melting/boiling point as some of the particles would have already changed state and others would not.

If you're asking more about characteristics then these are some examples I can think of:

- Evaporated water just leaves and the remaining water acts like liquid
- Water droplets which condense in clouds eventually stick to each other then fall down as rain
- Most of the melting of an ice block is on the outside and flows off, however what is inside is trapped